# Flutter Supabase join queries

Tags: flutter, dart, supabase, supabase-database

I have three tables in my social media app: `users` (stores user details), `connections`, and `posts`.

The `connections` table has the following columns:

- `id` (Primary Key)
- `uuid` (Foreign Key from `users` table)
- `circle` (List of UUIDs)
- `following` (List of UUIDs)
- `followers` (List of UUIDs)

The `posts` table has the following columns:

- `id` (Primary Key)
- `uuid` (Foreign Key from `users` table)
- `created_at` (Timestamp)
- `is_public` (Boolean)
- `content`

I need assistance with the following scenarios:

1. Scenario: Retrieving posts from users I'm following

   - For example, let's say I am user 'A', and I want to retrieve all the posts from the users I am following.
2. Scenario: Handling private posts visible to specific users

   - Suppose I am not included in the circle list of user 'B'. User 'B' has two posts, one is private, and the other is public.
   - As per our app's rules, only users in the circle should be able to view private posts.
   - How can I implement a solution to ensure that only users in the circle can read or view private posts?

How can I achieve the required outcome in Flutter Supabase?.
Thank you!

Comment: Yes this can be done with SQL.  SQL is a language to be learned separately, but is pretty useful when dealing with SQL databases.  Your queries will be single queries, but require the use of JOIN to relate columns in one table with columns in the next table.

Comment: As for privacy, Supabase has enabled "row level security", which means that tables and columns can be selectively enabled for groups of users.  This is not a topic I can answer in a chat field, but google "postgres row level security" for some basic information.

Comment: May you please write a code to achieve the following? @RandalSchwartz

Comment: There's a wealth of literature on designing and using and maintaining SQL databases, a lot of it for Pg in particular.  Searching for and reading this material will be better than any single example I can put here.

Answer (score 0):

Any complex queries like this will require you to write [database functions](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/database/functions) and calling it with the [.rpc()](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/dart/rpc) method from the Flutter app.

```dart
final data = await supabase.rpc('get_following_posts');
```